# Adding a new field to an existing content-type in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal and I'm looking for a way to add a new field to an already installed content-type in Drupal 7. Please note that some content is already present in the database. Also, I need to do this programmatically and not via a GUI.

Googling, I have already found the following documents, which seem to be related:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7

Still, my ideas are a bit confused and a basic example would clarify things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This snippet should get you started. It was found on the Drupal Stackexchange. I suggest you check there first in the future.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/programmatically-create-fields-in-drupal-7

```
$myField_name = "my_new_field_name";
if(!field_info_field($myField_name)) // check if the field already exists.
{
    $field = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'type'          => 'image',
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    $field_instance = array(
        'field_name'    => $myField_name,
        'entity_type'   => 'node',
        'bundle'        => 'CONTENT_TYPE_NAME',
        'label'         => t('Select an image'),
        'description'   => t(''),
        'widget'        => array(
            'type'      => 'image_image',
            'weight'    => 10,
        ),
        'formatter'     => array(
            'label'     => t('label'),
            'format'    => 'image'
        ),
        'settings'      => array(
            'file_directory'        => 'photos', // save inside "public://photos"
            'max_filesize'          => '4M',
            'preview_image_style'   => 'thumbnail',
            'title_field'           => TRUE,
            'alt_field'             => FALSE,
        )
    );
    field_create_instance($field_instance);
    drupal_set_message("Field created successfully!");
}
```

You can execute this code countless ways. I am not privy to the requirements of your project so its hard for me to make a recommendation. You could hook this into the update/install functions, or you could build it into a page hook in a module, or you could just bootstrap any new php file in the root directory with this:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I cannot uninstall or disable the module  because some content is already in the db, in which function should I add the new fields? Is the hook_update function the only way?

Comment: See my updated answer. Short answer is you can run this code many ways, it depends on if this is code you will need to run over and over, whether you want it part of a module install process, or if its just something you need to run once.

Comment: Quite a useful post, the module field_inspector, can help to export field definitions from the UI.